# RestTemplate getForObject worked fine for few hours and then threw 400 bad request which eventually changed to 494 UnsupportedHttpStatusCodeException

Tags: get, resttemplate, http-status-code-400, spring-webclient

I am trying to access a static json using getForObject method.
It worked fine for 14 hours and then started throwing 400 Bad Request.
After another 24 hours, it started to throw UnsupportedHttpStatusCodeException [494] null.

We use aws ec2 instance for hosting our application.
The issue occurs around 14 hours after the deployment and disappears after redeploying the application to just reappear after another 14 hours.
My client class has the below code.

```
public void getData(String apiUrl){
    try{
       LOGGER.info( "Using restTemplate getForObject" );
       Data response = restTemplate.getForObject( apiUrl, Data.class );
       LOGGER.info( "Response {}", response );
    }catch ( RestClientException e ){
       LOGGER.error( "Exception while getForObject : {}", e );
    }
}
```

Comment: My api config as the below:

Comment: @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate()
    {
       return new RestTemplate();
    }

Comment: My restclient class has the below code:
        
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
        
@Autowired
public void setRestTemplate( RestTemplate restTemplate ){
          this.restTemplate = restTemplate;}